# Audio.src and paths in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-os

I'm working on an app for Firefox OS < 1.3 to set your songs as ringtones.
The repo https://github.com/Mte90/RingTone-Picker-for-FirefoxOS and the file with the problem is script.js

In the line https://github.com/Mte90/RingTone-Picker-for-FirefoxOS/blob/master/script.js#L73 the path it's correct like "/emmc/audio.ogg" but the audio player return core error 4.
This problem is for a wrong path but the path is correct!

If i add on the line 74 `console.log(player.src)` return a path like "app://strangenumberhash/emmc/audio.ogg".
I have no absolutely idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app protocol is not allowed to be used to reference audio/video files within a packaged app. I believe this is a security restriction is to prevent cross app content reading. You need to either use an audio tag in your HTML or use an XMLHttpRequest.  Something like the following (video example):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'myvid.ogg');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
videoblob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'video/ogg' });
    var openingVideo = new MozActivity({
            name: "open",
            data: {
                type: [
                  "video/webm",
                  "video/mp4",
                  "video/3gpp",
                  "video/mkv",
                  "video/ogg"
                ],
                blob: videoblob
            }
        });                

};
xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Error loading test video', xhr.error.name);
};
```

If the file is on the SDCard you have a couple of options:

One you could just use a pick activity and let the user locate it:

```
var act = new MozActivity({
    name: 'pick',
    data: {
      type: 'audio/ogg'
    }
    });
```

or you can set the readwrite permission on the sdcard in the manifest and read it manually and play it with the audio tag or with a open activity (very little error checking).

```
var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage('sdcard');
//assumes sample.ogg is located at the top of the sdcard
var request = sdcard.get("sample.ogg");

request.onsuccess = function () {
  var file = this.result;
  console.log("Get the file: " + file.name);
  var mysrc = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var audio1 = new Audio();
  audio1.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(" error playing file ");
  }
  audio1.src =  mysrc;
  audio1.type = "video/ogg";
  console.log( "audio src " + audio1.src);
  audio1.play();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
request.onerror = function () {
  console.warn("Unable to get the file: ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the solution not work :-/ i get NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: in the console on xhr.send(); the new code https://github.com/Mte90/RingTone-Picker-for-FirefoxOS/blob/master/script.js#L75 . The path it's getted with the DeviceStorage API :-//

Comment: if the audio/vid file is in the packaged app you should be able to use a relative url, not DeviceStorage.  In the above example, if myvid.ogg was located in the packaged app's vid direcotry I would have used xhr.open('GET', 'vid/myvid.ogg');

Comment: BTW if you are doing audio only change the type to something like: type: [
  "audio/mpeg",
  "audio/ogg",
  "audio/mp4"
]

Comment: the file it's not in the packaged apps, is in the sdcard :-/